# How to dynamically switch between CPU and GPU with TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying Q-learning with TensorFlow. In order to run my agent I need to repeatedly call my model with a batch size of one (containing the current state and computing the q-outputs). I collect those steps and perform the training of the network in big batches of 1000 such steps.

This means that I run a tiny computation 1000 times and then run a big computation 1 time. And this in an infinite loop.

It seems that the tiny computations should run on the CPU and the big one on the GPU. **How can I achieve that?** It seems that device placement in TensorFlow is statically determined when creating the graph nodes.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem? Calling session.run() on GPU repeatedly causes massive overhead, when sampling actions.

Comment: @flxh I have no easy solution so far for switching devices. I optimized the Q-learning by running many agents in parallel. That way I can issue large calls to the GPU even during agent execution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `with tf.device('/cpu:0')` ?
like this:

```
# Creates a graph.
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

This assigns `a` and `b` on `cpu:0` and the rest of session runs on `gpu:0`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to run the same graph on changing devices.